# Multi-conditional conditional formatting question

Tags: excel, colors, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am currently applying conditional formatting to a table.

I have a rule that states if a certain cell in column B contains a course that begins "B6", then excel needs to color the adjacent cell in column C, blue.

The thing is, the column that would contain B6 changes depending every semester since the courses also change. So for example, a course that starts with "B6" in cell B5 may very well change to a course that starts with "B80" in the future.

That said, to combat potential changes I am going one by and adding conditional formatting formulas for each row/cell.

**Here is an example:**

[Conditional Format Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfVXb.png) - Here you can see that if cell B4 contains "B6" it should format accordingly -- at this time it does not have "B6" so it's blank. On the other hand, B5 contains "B6" so it should format accordingly -- which it does in this case.

[Formatting Outcome on the Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocynb.png) - this is what it looks like on the sheet.

**My Question**

So as you can see I am going one by one and applying the conditional formatting to each cell one by one. I have to apply the color blue if each cell contains "B6", and the color orange if each cell contains "B80" and so forth. Is there anyway I can make a formula so that I only have to make one rule per color for each column instead of conditionally formatting each cell?

EDIT:
[Update with relative referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Nz5.jpg) - I followed your link and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you considered using named ranges? [This superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/867092/apply-conditional-formatting-to-multiple-rows) may also be helpful for applying conditional formatting to a multiple cells at once

Comment: Do not make the row in the formula absolute and use an applies to area that encompasses the whole area.

Comment: I just tried your suggestions and it does not seem to work. @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: The formula would be `=LEFT($B4,2)="B6"` The row on the formula must match the lowest row in the `Applies to:` range.

Comment: I misinterpreted @Scott Craner's comment as meaning the bottom row of the range - no, I'm pretty sure it's the top row i.e. the lowest row _number_ -:)

Comment: @ScottCraner: that worked! Thank you